# PHP 5.3.27 on CentOS 6.4

Tags: php, centos6

Can someone tell me how to setup PHP 5.3.27 on CentOS 6.4 without using remi repos and without compiling PHP myself?

I tried googling a lot but it always gives me results for upgrade on CentOS 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following

```
# rpm --import http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
# rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

# rpm --import http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/IUS-COMMUNITY-GPG-KEY
# rpm -ivh http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/6/x86_64/ius-release-1.0-11.ius.el6.noarch.rpm
```

After that

```
# yum search php53u
```

Comment: Tnx, I removed php* packages and then installed same php53u* packages and now it is working like intended.